# Flutter image_picker video gallery OSError: Operation not permitted [Errno 1] IOS 13

Tags: ios, flutter, imagepicker

I am using flutter image_picker and almost all is good except for when i try to do something with file generated on pickVideo from gallery (just on IOS 13 real device) it give error:

> OSError: Operation not permitted [Errno 1].

Some extrange is that this video file can play with video_player and i can work good with camera file and image pick file generated with image_picker, but video gallery file can not do another thing than play with video_player.

For example, trying to get file size or copy it to another file fails, code example:

```
var videoFile = await ImagePicker.pickVideo(source: ImageSource.gallery);

print("File path........${videoFile.path}");
print("...................Size: ${await videoFile.length()}");

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;

File newfile = videoFile.copy("${appDocPath}/video.MOV");
```

I saw that all permissions are good, mainly `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` on `Info.plist`, but it does not work.

I need to say that on android all is working fine.

I hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 1):

please go through the documentation of Image_picker where it says for ios setup:

Add the following keys to your Info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist:

```
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription 
NSCameraUsageDescription 
NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
```

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I have done that already, thats because images and camera works fine but video do not.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem using another library call file_picker, i think image_piker is not workin good since IOS 13, they need upgrade it.